# How to include a Google Sheets cell number in XPath for ImportXML

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm playing with Google Scripts & Sheets.

I want to extract the text in p for every query in a specific url. This works:

```
=IMPORTXML("url", "//h3[text()=‘query’]/following-sibling::p[1]")
```

However, instead of copying and pasting each query, I have a column of almost 200 of them (I'm aware of the 50 limit). Is there a way to replace text()=‘query’ with a cell? E.g.

```
=IMPORTXML("url", "//h3[B3]/following-sibling::p[1]")
```

I've tried many variations of B3/what's contained in [] e.g. GetRange("B3"), all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using standard string concatanation:

```
=IMPORTXML("url", "//h3["&B3&"]/following-sibling::p[1]")
```

Comment: Thank you! That gives me #N/A strangely.

Comment: Have you checked what you get when you hardcode the xpath?